# The Toolbar with AppCompatActivity in android cover whole area of upper side on device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have used AppCompatActivity to show my toolbar on my android app but it hide whole upper part of my mobile devices.I have tried all kind of theme but can't able to figure it out how to decrease the height of toolbar from 
upper side.

My xml file is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#f04d3c"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/search_icon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="#f04d3c"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/cart_icon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#f04d3c"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/notification_icon" />





    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">



        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/navList"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
            android:childDivider="@drawable/child_list_divider"
            />


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

and my style is this which use Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#f04d3c</item>
        <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#f04d3c</item>
        <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

My app image is this
[image: This is what my app look]

Comment: It is not toolbar at the top, it is just statusBar with red(same) color as like Toolbar.

Answer (score 4):

Within your styles.xml, set a different color for "colorPrimaryDark".

The status bar above your Toolbar takes the color that you specify in colorPrimaryDark. Since your colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark are same, it looks like its just a large Toolbar.

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">CHANGE_COLOR_HERE</item>
```

If you wish to restore the color to default, you can set it to transparent

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Lollipop and above, the default is that the ActionBar color reflects on the status bar.

Some solutions are : -

1. If you extend Activity instead of AppCompatActivity, this will actually not happen
2. If you want to set the status bar black or transparent, or any color you want, you can always do `getActivity().getWindow().setStatusBarColor(R.id.your_color)`
3. As mentioned by @Rachit, you can set a colorPrimaryDark